# Hibernate Search Additional Search Criterias

Tags: java, hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

I've been working on a demonstrative application for a shopping web app. I am using Spring + Hibernate to manage things on the back-end server. Now, as I would like the users of the application to be able to search through the products like they search stuff on google, I came to the conclusion that Hibernate Search fits my needs the best. However, I would like administrators of the app to be able to search stuff by providing search filters for multiple attributes. For example the "PRODUCT" table has fields such as id, name, desc, created_date etc, I want to provide the admin a way they could provide different inputs such as partial data for id, name, desc and created_date and could obtain the relevant search results. Hibernate Search allows me to do that by combining queries with clause like "and", "should" etc. But, in order to implement that I would have to annotate all the searchable fields with @Field annotation.

My question here is if it would be wise to annotate all the searchable attributes with @Field or is there any other way to tackle the same problem?

Comment: Could you explain what's bothering you exactly? The amount of fields to annotate? The simple fact of adding annotations to a class? Something else?

Comment: I'm bothered about the performance of the queries. If I try to index all the columns like if i have a field named "create_user_id" and I want the user to be able to perform fulltext search over it as well, will indexing that field in hibernate search along with all the other fields decrease the performance?

Comment: Ok, then I second @Sanne's answer: just annotate all the fields you need. Don't worry about performance until you actually tried the tool and noticed an issue, you'll probably just waste your time. The people working on Lucene (the engine behind Hibernate Search) already spent a great deal of time optimizing, so unless your use case is really exotic (say, hundreds or thousands of fields), Lucene should handle this just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to simply annotate all fields you need with *@Field*